# Streaming audio with python lags when threaded

Tags: python, multithreading, audio

I am making a program resembling skype. Currently , I had implemented basic chat and audio chat features. I use sockets , stкeam and pyaudio for those features. Since I am trying to implement group calls , I need the audio data from the server to be streamed to all connected clients (ip/port). I use threading for this.

This is when I need your help. Basically , when I use threading , regardless of whether I have a lock on the thread of not , the sound lags. Although , I would think , it should not lag at all when I use a lock , since then the audio is transmitted only to one client , and the other thread waits for the first to complete (I know it makes no sense to use such a technique , just saying). So what is causing the lag while threading ? How to eliminate it ?

And also , there is something weird going on with the playback. On one machine , the audio plays back from the client perfectly, while on an other it is nothing but white noise with some elements of me trying to scream in my mic. Why is that ? Any ideas ?

Thank you. Sorry , I cannot share the code , but I will answer any questions regarding it.

(added)

Here is a very simplified version of the code , with only the important bits edited in.

```
import socket  
import time
import threading
import random
import pyaudio
import wave
from multiprocessing import Process


s = socket.socket()        
host = '192.168.2.21'    
port = 5001                
s.bind((host, port))

(meaningless variable declaration was here)
print ('Server Started.')


def playback_f(pass_record, soc, client, port_a, data, c):

    try:

        pass_record = False

        print ('in else')

        stop_recording = False
        try :
            print ('tried')
            soc.sendto('playback'.encode('utf-8'),(client,port_a))
            print ('sent','playback'.encode('utf-8'))
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)

        while stop_recording == False:

            if data !=  b'stop_rec':

                try:
                    data = c.recv(1024)
                    soc.sendto(data,(client,port_a))

                except Exception as e:
                    print (e)

            else:
                stop_recording = True

        print('ended')


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def client_worker(isMessage,c,addr,message,alias,quitting,clients,rooms,room_connections):

    while quitting != True:

        try:

            isMessage = False

            data, addr1 = c.recvfrom(1024)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(data,addr)
            curAddr = addr[0]

            (bunch of code here that has nothing to do with anything)

                                    try:
                                        #print('trying to send : ' + message, (client,port_a))
                                        soc.sendto(('alias_' + alias).encode('utf-8'), (client,port_a))
                                        soc.sendto(('message_' + message).encode('utf-8'), (client,port_a))
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        print(e)

                                else:

                                    try:
                                        p_r = Process(target = playback_f, args = (pass_record, soc, client, port_a, data, c)).start()

                                    except Exception as e:
                                        print(e)


                            except Exception as e:
                                print (e)
(more code here)

while True: 
    print (clients)
    c, addr1 = s.accept() 
    threading.Thread(target = client_worker,args = (isMessage,c,addr1,message,alias,quitting,clients,rooms,room_connections)).start()
```

So , to make is simple to read , what this thing (the server) does is :

It receives some data from the client. If the client indicates that it wants to stream audio , the server grabs it , and streams it to all the clients in a given room (each client has not create or enter an existing room in order to chat).

The problematic bit is : p_r = threading.Thread(target = playback_f, args = (pass_record, soc, client, port_a, data, c)).start()

which causes the sound to lag. I just tried to do

p_r = Process(target = playback_f, args = (pass_record, soc, client, port_a, data, c)).start()

instead, but it does not work and gives me a bunch of errors like : only one connection can exist at a time and pointing to s.bind((host, port)). Although I never attempt to make a new connection , I only caall playback_f() using the "Process".

I am very confused at this point.

p.s. all the client does is that it send a signal "recording_" to the server and then starts sending it the audio data. It also receives it and plays it back.

Comment: `threading.Thread`s can't be run in parallel because of GIL. If you want true multithreading, use `multiprocessing` or switch to a different Python implementation (other than CPython). Also, sharing a [mcve] is _essential_ here.

Comment: Done. Mind taking a look ?